# Remove # from "go to symbol in workspace" command

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can never find the js files I'm looking for when the # is present in the search bar. So every time I want to search for something I have to first remove the # which is getting annoying.

Does anyone know of a setting that removes that # from automatically being placed in the search bar?

[image]

Comment: Are you just looking for files: Ctrl+P, if you are looking for Symbols: Ctrl+T

Comment: I like that i can reach the search command with one hand so swapping the keyboard shortcut of the commands works great, thx Mark!

Answer (score 0):

Type ctrl+P (command+p in mac) to search for files